# Did early hard drives lose data from it getting read too many times?

Tags: electromagnetism, data, computer

According to wikipedia, early HDD drives used to use an electromagnet to 'write' data on a small region by magnetizing it. I also read in that same article, however, that they also 'read' the data using electromagnetic induction (presumably a small wire hovers around the region, and if there's some minimum current $I_m$ the region is magnetized. Not sure if current direction would matter in a model).

However, whenever the data is 'read', there is energy required when producing the current within the electromagnet, and so the magnetization of the small region decreases. Another way to arrive at this conclusion is that the current, when the electromagnet experiences induction, runs in a direction so as to produce a magnetic field in the opposite direction of the field produced by the small region (assuming the induction happens because the head moves near the region), and so the opposite direction magnetic field would demagnetize the small region some amount.

Was it possible for the region to be read so much that it was no longer magnetized, and so data was lost as a result? Also, was this ever a problem?

Comment: I remember old cassette tapes getting worn put if you played them too much but I'm not sure if it's the same process at work- and I did accidentally wipe a load of tapes once by putting a magnet in the same drawer.

Comment: I would guess cassette tapes would get worn more often by mechanical wear-and-tear, but I don't know for sure. The magnet thing also makes sense, but that's more an outside effect. My question is whether the process of simply checking the data will wear it out if the electromagnetic induction way of checking data is implemented.

Comment: Might [retrocomputing.se] be better suited for this question?

Comment: Actually, I think so, at least for the second part of my question ("Was this ever a problem?").  The only concepts I considered were induction and energy loss, so I guess I don't expect the physics analysis to be incorrect and should just ask the second part of my question there. Can this thread be moved over, or should I close it and copy and paste everything?

Comment: No, early HDDs lost data because they crashed, ALL the time. I found this out the hard/expensive way.

Comment: I agree that that is how it commonly occurs. Is this another possible (not necessarily efficient) way to lose data?

Comment: By the time that hard drives were being commonly used for long-term storage (roughly mid-60s) this was not a "major" problem.  The drives would wear out (bearing failure, etc) or suffer a "head crash" long before the loss of magnetism was a issue, in most cases.  I am recalling, though, that, perhaps up to about 1980, it was common to occasionally run the drive through a complete read/write, "copy to self" cycle to "clean up" things a bit (though this was more to correct timing errors, etc, than to "fix" magnetization, I suspect).

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com may be a better match.